# how to Javascript toggle ID of div generated on runtime

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I am sending a Model to a View in MVC,

and for each "Person" in my Model, I want to create a button that says "Show Details", when the user clicks it, a div with more information about that person toggles.

I am generating a `a href` and  `div` id assigned to each person ID like the following:

```
   foreach (var person in Model.Persons)
        {
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="@Html.Raw("showDetails-" + @person.id)">Show Details</a>
        </div> 
        <div id="@Html.Raw("detailsDiv-" + @person.id)">
        <!--Content Here -->
        </div>

        }
```

I want to create the javascript that toggles on a click event

So I want to write this script but with the unique id for each person:

**I want to get the id of the div that needs to be toggled.**

I tried writing the script inside the foreach loop so I can be able to read the @person.id value, but it didnt work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#showDetails-@person.id").click(function () {
            $("#details-@person.id").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you do it by ID? Add a class (or have a common identifier) and add the same handler to all, then inside it just use `this` to refer to the current one.

Comment: @vlaz the id is the thing in common between the <a> and the <div> ids. when i click <a> with id=1 , i need to toggle <div> with id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a class to your links like `class="showDetails"`.

Now you Can create a global Event for all that links:

```
$('.showDetails').click(function(e) {
   var id = this.id // extract id.. split with '-' or whatever..
   $('#details-' + id).toggle();
});
```

Comment: also `.Click()` -> `.click()`

Answer (score 1):

you could put the id in a tag like "person_id" and use a class to trigger the jquery event.

```
<div class="middle_right">
        <a class="showDetails" href="#" person_id="@Html.Raw("showDetails-" + @person.id)">Show Details</a>
</div>
```

and in js

```
$(".showDetails").click(function () {
        var person_id=$(this).attr("person_id")
});
```